# Warn before accidentally committing with `-a`?

Tags: git

I often commit with `git commit -a`. Then again, I sometimes stage individual files with `git add` and commit without `-a`. When I’m not careful it happens that I type `-a` by accident when I had previously prepared a meticulously crafted staging area for my next commit, which I will then have to re-craft if I’m serious about keeping distinct changes in separate commits.

Is there a way of preventing that? Ideally git should ask about (or flatly refuse) the `-a` switch if (and only if) some changes are already staged. I think there should be a config for that but I couldn’t find it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix approach here.

You don't need `git` support to get a simple warning. You can write a wrapper script or a shell function that will examine command line parameters and take action accordingly.

This function should work in `bash` (add it to your `.bashrc` maybe) or even in plain `sh`.

```
git() {
   local found
   found=0
   for option; do
      if [ "$option" = "-a" ]; then found=1; break; fi
   done
   if [ "$found" -eq 1 ]
   then
      read -p "Option \`-a' detected. Please confirm with capital Y:" -r key
      [ "$key" != "Y" ] && return 254
   fi
   command git "$@"
}
```

Alternatively a script instead of a function:

```
#!/bin/sh

found=0
for option; do
   if [ "$option" = "-a" ]; then found=1; break; fi
done
if [ "$found" -eq 1 ]
then
   read -p "Option \`-a' detected. Please confirm with capital Y:" -r key
   [ "$key" != "Y" ] && return 254
fi
exec "/full/path/to/git" "$@"
```

Name the script `git`, make it executable and place it in a directory that is in your `$PATH` before the directory with the real `git`. `$HOME/bin` may be the right place; my Debian even supplies `.profile` (via `/etc/skel/.profile`) that adds this path to `PATH` automatically (if the directory exists). Just remember that any tool (e.g. a script) that relies on `$PATH` to call `git` will call your wrapper script from now on. You may not want this. If so, use the shell function approach.

The whole procedure is a proof of concept, it may be suboptimal. It doesn't yet care about your "if (and only if) some changes are already staged" condition. I'm not familiar with `git` but I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1587877) provides a way to check against it:

> ```
> git diff --cached
> ```

Use it to expand the logic of your function or script. Keep in mind you need `/full/path/to/git` to avoid your script calling itself and getting stuck in a loop (like a fork bomb without forking, a chain bomb). The function should use `/full/path/to/git` or `command git` for the very same reason.

Also you may want to replace `[ "$option" = "-a" ]` with something like

```
[[ "$option" =~ ^-[a-zA-Z0-9]*a[a-zA-Z0-9]* ]]
```

to cover cases where `a` is given with other switches in a compact form (e.g. `-Pa`). The `[[` command [is not portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168261/108618) though.

Comment: Thanks for the script. Unfortunately it does not handle the case where `a` is part of a list of shorthand options (like `git commit -am`, `git commit -Pa`), but other than that it’s pretty great and I can easily code the stage condition myself.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Instead of `[ ... ]` use `[[ "$option" =~ ... ]]` in `bash`. The `=~` treats the string to the right as an extended regular expression.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert I have added `[[` example at the end of the answer.